# Error when writing dataframe with PySpark

Tags: pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql, impala

I am not able to save a table to any of a few different sources.
I have tried the following:

- `dataset.toPandas().to_csv("local_path")`
- `dataset.createOrReplaceTempView("tempTable")`
  `spark.sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS impala_table")`
  `spark.sql((f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS impala_table AS "`
             `"SELECT * from tempTable"))`
- `dataset.write.overwrite().saveAsTable("impala_table")`
- `dataset.write.csv(file, header=True, mode="overwrite")`

So, my deduction is that it's not even getting to writing it in any form, but I can't figure out how to know more about it.
The error logs are if not the same, very similar.  The one I found most odd regards a `module named "src" that is not found`.  This is what I found most repetitive and pertinent:

```
/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera4-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.611179/
lib/spark2/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in 
get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name) 
    326 raise Py4JJavaError( 
    327 "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328 format(target_id, ".", name), value) 
    329 else: 
    330 raise 
Py4JError( Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o877.saveAsTable. : 
  org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted. at     
  org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.
  write(FileFormatWriter.scala:224)

...

File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2-2.3.0.cloudera4-1.cdh5.13.3.p0.611179/
  lib/spark2/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 566, 
  in loads return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

Thanks for checking it out.
Cheers.

Comment: Could this error be due to `dataset.write.saveAsTable("impala_table")` without `mode("overwrite")` perhaps? I suspect that the error is due to the `impala_table` being already available.

Comment: Oh. The table doesn't exist, so I tried removing it and left it like that.  In any case, that Im sure I tried before.

Comment: Are you able to `show()` the  dataset before attempting any of those save operations?

Comment: @kfkhalili no, that throws the same error.  I also tried `describe` and `head` with the same error.

Comment: Actually, I'm coming to think it has to do with that specific dataset, not on spark itself.  Given its particular pipeline, and involving a user defined `ColumnDropper` stage, I'm thinking that might be the issue.

Comment: @Diego-MX yes, it makes sense to occasionally `show` the dataset at different points in the pipeline to force the lazy transformations to happen and verify correctness. Of course, having comprehensive unit testing helps too.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the problem behind this dataframe.
This was not something about the writer, but on the intermediate table calculations.

As @kfkhalili pointed out, it's a good recommendation to do sporadic `.show()`s in order to verify it's running smoothly.

Thanks.